# Selenium IDE alert(); fail during test

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium IDE, when I put alert:

```
Command: storeEval
Target: alert("Please validate, then press OK!")
```

After I press OK, the test crash. The log of this crash is:

```
[info] script is: alert("Please validate, then press OK!")
[error] Threw an exception: 
[info] Test case failed
```

The weird is, sometime works perfect, sometime not.

Comment: maybe you should add a sleep or wait for element to appear before validating the alert.

Comment: Hi, I put this alert, only to have some time to check somewhere, after I check I want to continue the test, then press OK